# Storing authenticated facebook users in a Database

Tags: android, database, facebook, web-services, authentication

I'm trying to find the correct way to store in a database & authenticate a user who logged into my app using facebook:

So the first time the user logs into the app, a webservice 'sees' this user isn't in the database and inserts its data. The second time the user logs in, the app contacts the webservice and gets some information about this user, only available to the user himself, such as his api key for communicating with the webservice.

But this requires authentication, so the webservice won't give the api key to anyone but the user. It's easy to authenticate the client using facebook on client-side, but then how would the webservice know this authentication took place? I've read a lot on this issue here on SO and came to realize I should store the (hashed) OAuth access token as the user's password, and then send this token on login to the webservice so it could match between the stored token in the database and the received token, thus authenticate the user.

**But, tokens expire**. So when this token expires, the user should re-authenticate on client-side using facebook and the webservice should recieve a new token. At this point, the webservice would try to match between this new token and the old one stored in the database, and it would fail. So the webservice should update the token and then authenticate it but how can the webservice know that this token has originated from the app and is valid, and not a token sent by someone else? How can the webservice even know the old token expired, and not that someone is just trying to cause this token replacment to occur (eg. an attacker sending random password). This token replacement basically breaks the whole point of storing the token in the first place, since any different token would just replace the old one.

So basically the problem is - how can I securely update an existing user's token once the previous one expired?

I apologize for the long text to read, I've been studying this issue for 2 days now and I'm just missing something important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user has already authorized your application. Facebook will return you a valid access token without any user facing dialog. However if the user has de-authorized your application then the user will need to re-authorize your application for you to get the access_token.

You should read this, hopefully help your understanding :-)

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/05/13/how-to--handle-expired-access-tokens/

It's for PHP but should translate into android.

Basically you just request a new token with the stored oauth data.

Comment: So when I receive a different token than the one inside the database, I should use the one in the database to request the new token from facebook and check if the result matches to the token sent from client-side?

Comment: @Eran Correct, you should then receive a new token back and you can update your db with the new one, alternatively, if you are really struggling with this, take a look at socialauth

Comment: A problem I just encountered - the token stored in the database is hashed, so I can't use it to get a new token. Should I just store the tokens in plain text (is it unsafe for tokens like is it for passwords?) or encrypt them in a two-way AES encryption?

Comment: store them in plain text I think is the suggested route, they are useless without your consumer key/secret